# edit my profile biography

Tags: support, status-bydesign, profile-page

How can I edit my profile biography? It needs some fixing. There are typo errors and I can add a thing or two etc. I was trying to find it myself, but to no avail, I didn't succeed in finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This only works on a desktop browser, not mobile.

Click on your icon at the top of the page, and you will be presented with your Activity screen. Just under the site title bar, you'll see Profile, Activity, Edit Profile & Settings, Meta User and Network Profile.

Simply click on Edit Profile & Settings

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get what you showed me. I made a print screen but I don't know how to send it to you

Comment: I only get two options profile and activity. When I'm in profile I don't get the same screen that you get. Now that I'm writing this, I'm thinking its only afew days that I don't get that screen. Before that I remember I did get it?

Comment: How strange - I'll try and figure out why. My example for me was on a site where I have very low rep and I'm not a mod, so I assumed it would be a good example.

Comment: Your doing wonderful good work! Where the credit is due, we need to give it

Comment: With 161 rep you should be able to upload an image I think. Use the image upload button.

Comment: Where is this button? I feel like a jerk

Comment: If you edit your post, there should be a row of icons for adding attachments, images, text formatting etc. Do you see them?

Comment: It could be since I'm using my window phone that why I don't have the edit button etc. The first weeks I was on the forum I'm sure that I had all that. When I want to edit, I don't have all the buttons that I use to have. I uploaded an example, links, etc. Can you check if it's the problem with the Smart phone?

Comment: Ahh - it's not a problem with phones. You just have limited functionality on mobile by design. You'll need to use a desktop browser instance.

Comment: What changed before I did have the whole screen?

Comment: Check 'em out! I did it. I would really like to know what changed? It's only maybe a week and ahalf that I can't do this on my smart phone?

Comment: Not sure why. I've never seen those buttons on mobile, only on either a desktop or a desktop view on mobile